# Casting a COM object 3 ways

Tags: c#, exception, com, com-interop

I have a C+ addin in Excel that needs to pass a com object from a com dll (written in Delphi) to a com+ dll written in c#.

So I have:

- c# - CSStore and EsAddin.
- Delphi - KSrvr

kSrvr has an Object `Job` that is returned from a method.  CSStore has a mehod that takes a `KSrvr.Job`.  But it will not let me pass the Job object I got from the kSrvr instance to the CSStore instance in the EsAddin.  Note these cannot be registered in the GAC unless no alternative.

```
KSrvr k = new KSrvr();
kSrvr.Job aJob = k.Application.CurrentJob();

CSStore c = new CSStore();
c.QueueJob (aJob);
```

gives the exception

> "The argument type 'System.__ComObject' cannot be converted into parameter type 'KSrvr.Job'."

I have tried using:

```
kSrvr.Job aJob = k.Application.CurrentJob() as KSrvr.Job
```

but that was the same exception and `aJob` is still a `__ComObject`.

trying to get the job by using

```
KSrvr.Job aJob = (KSrvr.Job)Marshal.CreateWrapperOfType (
  k.Application.CurrentJob(), 
  typeof KSrvr.Job));
```

gives the exception

> error the Type must be __ComObject or derived from __ComObject

How can I do this has anyone any ideas?

Comment: have you tried using `dynamic`?

Comment: Ahh thank you that works did not knwo about the use of that